# How to change the default title font in jQuery colorbox

Tags: jquery, css, title

I am integrating this jQuery solution into a website:

http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

The title tag style for each picture slideshow in the original code is inherited from the body style. However in my solution I cannot use this and the title appears with it's default font - Times new roman.

Is there an easy way to change the font family for the image slideshow to something else, either by CSS or directly in the plugin code?

I have tried this directly in the plugin code but then the title disappears:

```
$title = $tag(div, "<span style='font:12px/1.2 Verdana, sans-serif;'>Title</span>")
```

However, changing the style directly in the plugin code works for the Image count:

```
current: "<span style='font:12px/1.2 Verdana, sans-serif;'>Image {current} of {total}</span>",
```

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color box title is inside a div element with id `cboxTitle`, you can override its style using css like:

```
#cboxTitle {
    font-family: Georgia !important;
    font-weight: bold !important;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/U7fmz/